# How to set background of radio button opaque /transparent?

Tags: swift, macos, radio-button, background-color

I in my swift project for Mac I want to use radio buttons, but with the same color, my background has. How can I set my background on opaque or change my background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem. Set the text of the radio button to „“, add the rb to a horizontal stack view and then add a label to this stack view and set it‘s background colour to the bc of the view.